# Is it possible to get the Task object that is returned from an async function, INSIDE that function?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

As title. Say I have a function:

```
async Task Foo()
{
    // get Task obj that will be returned from this function
}
```

Is it possible to get a reference to that Task object?

The reason I'm curious about this, is because I want to be able to keep track of some tasks.

Comment: Could you move that logic into a new `InnerFoo`? And then use the `InnerFoo` `Task` from `Foo`?

Comment: What do you mean by _I want to be able to keep track of some tasks_?  If the Task inside of `Foo` is awaited then the task returned by `Foo` will not complete until that one does.

Comment: Did you have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700809/how-to-get-the-current-task-reference ?

Comment: You can't *literally* do this, because the compiler-generated code will not actually produce the task until the end -- so, in a very real sense, there *is* no `Task` object inside the method. There are probably many alternative ways of achieving what you want, but that involves taking a step back and detailing your actual scenario.

Comment: you are actually asking whether one can access the return value of a method inside the method.

Comment: The link posted by @vsarunov comes closest to what I wanted, but seeing the complexity has made me reconsider this.

Comment: @juharr: I did not want to await the Task inside the function, just add it to a list inside the same class that owns the function, but is not the caller of the function. But I'm going to go a different route now :-). Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 2):

The `Task` that is returned from the function is the one generated from `await Boo()` (if the inner work is done by a function `Boo`)
So you can use:

```
Task booTask = Boo();
```

without `await` to get that task.

Comment: That is unfortunately not true for some corner cases, like ValueTask and Custom Awaiters

Comment: @user1781290 : generally, an async method return a task that is created somewhere, so you can save that created task instead of using `await`

Comment: async methods are usually not returning a Task explicitly, but implicitly. Still my point stands, that there are cases where you `await` an object that is not `Task`